# Angular column sort clicking header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm trying to enable sorting on all the data, as I'm also doing pagination on the client side. I'm having another issue with the paging that it is only showing the first 25 records and when I change pages, the new set of 25 records does not show, but I would like to figure out this sorting issue.

```
function DataUploadHistoryController($window, $scope, $modal, $state, toaster, PagerService, DataUploadHistoryFactory, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.uploads = [];
    vm.includeCancelled = false;
    vm.uploadDataModal = {};
    vm.pager = {};
    vm.setPage = setPage;
    vm.itemsByPage=25;
    $scope.sortType = 'uploadDate';
    $scope.sortReverse = true;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        getUploadHistory();
        $scope.$watch('vm.includeCancelled', getUploadHistory);
        $scope.$on('closeUploadModal', function(event, response) {
            if (vm.uploadDataModal.opened) {
                vm.uploadDataModal.close();
                getUploadHistory();

                var poller = function() {
                    DataUploadHistoryFactory.getUploadById(response.dataLoadExecutionId).success(function(response) {
                        if(response.status.statusCd !== 'NEW'){
                            if(response.status.statusCd === 'ERROR')
                                toaster.error('Could not load execution. Please remove.');
                            else
                                toaster.success('Data execution load complete.');
                            getUploadHistory();
                            return;
                        }
                        $timeout(poller, 5000);
                    })
                }
                poller();

            };
        });
        $scope.$on('cancelUploadModal', function(event, response) {
            if (vm.uploadDataModal.opened) {
                vm.uploadDataModal.close();
                getUploadHistory();

            };
        });
        /*
        $scope.$on('closeDownloadTemplateModal', function() {
            if (vm.downloadTemplateModal.opened)
                vm.downloadTemplateModal.close();
        });
        */
    }

    var checkProcessingPoller = function() {
        DataUploadHistoryFactory.getUploadHistory(vm.includeCancelled).then(
                function(response) {
                    _.each(response.data, function(upload) {
                        if(upload.processing = upload.status && ['PROCESSING'].indexOf(upload.status.statusCd.trim()) > -1){
                            $timeout(checkProcessingPoller, 5000);
                            console.log("Checking Status");
                        }
                    });
                    vm.uploads = response.data;
                });
    }
    checkProcessingPoller();

    function getUploadHistory() {
        DataUploadHistoryFactory.getUploadHistory(vm.includeCancelled).then(
            function(response) {
                _.each(response.data, function(upload) {
                    upload.inProgress = upload.status && ['INPROGRESS','NEW'].indexOf(upload.status.statusCd.trim()) > -1;
                });
                vm.uploads = response.data;

                if($state.params.reupload){
                    uploadProductionData();
                    $state.params.reupload = false;
                }
                vm.setPage(1);
                vm.itemsByPage=25;
            });
    }

    $scope.sortBy = function(keyName){
        $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
        $scope.sortType = keyName;
    };
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="chrthdr" ui-view="header"></div>
<div id="userResults">
<div class="card card-full-width">
    <div class="card-header dark-blue">
        <a class="card-config" data-toggle="uploadHistory" data-placement="left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
        <div class="card-title">Data History</div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-horizontal range-date' style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <form>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px;  margin-right: 5px" type="button" ng-click="vm.uploadProductionData()">Upload Data</span>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.includeCancelled">Include removed executions
                    </label>
                    <!--<span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px" type="button" ng-click="vm.viewTemplates()">Download Template</span>-->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-click="sortBy('uploadDate')" >Upload Date
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'uploadDate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'uploadDate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                            <th ng-click="sortBy('templateName')">Template
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'templateName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'templateName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Last Updated By</th>
                            <th>Last Updated</th>
                            <th>Status
                                <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="upload in vm.uploads | orderBy:'uploadDate':true | limitTo: vm.itemsByPage">
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.uploadDate}}</td>
                            <td>{{upload.product}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.comments}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.templateName}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.lastUpdatedByUser}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.lastUpdateDate}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.status.statusName}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px; " ng-hide="upload.status.statusCd === 'NEW' || upload.status.statusCd === 'ERROR'" ng-click="vm.loadStagingPage(upload.dataLoadExecutionId, upload.product, upload.status)">View</button>
                                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px; " type="button" ng-click="vm.cancelDataExecution(upload.dataLoadExecutionId)" ng-show="upload.inProgress || upload.status.statusCd === 'ERROR'">Remove</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <div class="text-center">
                   <ul ng-if="vm.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(1)">First</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-repeat="page in vm.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:vm.pager.currentPage === page}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                        </li>               
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the header clicks is pretty simple. Here's what you currently have:

`ng-repeat="upload in vm.uploads | orderBy:'uploadDate':true | limitTo: vm.itemsByPage"`

It needs to be updated to:

`ng-repeat="upload in vm.uploads | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | limitTo: vm.itemsByPage"`

In order for reverse to work correctly when switching columns, it needs to check if the current sorted item is selected:

```
$scope.sortBy = function(keyName){
    if($scope.sortType === keyName) {
        $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
    } else {
        $scope.sortReverse = false;
    }
    $scope.sortType = keyName;
    console.log('Type', $scope.sortType, 'Reverse', $scope.sortReverse);
};
```

Comment: Thank you - the orginal orderBy I had by uploadDate was the default sort I wanted to display - is there a way to maintain the default sort?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you. Since you defined it at the top (`$scope.sortType = 'uploadDate';`), it will default to that when that controller is first hit

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i also implemented paging with google logic on here, and it breaks each page into results of 25, and when i select a sort, it sorts based on the results just for that page - so if there is a sort on template name on page 1, it will only sort those alphabetically for the results shows on page 1, not the entire result set, so when i goto another page, the same sort will be there, but it again it only sorts the 25 records on that particular page.

Comment: The end result I'd like is when a sort is selected, it will sort for the entire data set, not just the results which are showing. Can I do that within my sortBy function?

Comment: What you're asking for is server-side pagination. You'll need to see if whatever data you're pulling from supports parameters like order, sort, and skip/take.

Comment: I thought there is ways to do this if I'm doing pagination completely on client side?

Comment: Take the first call for an example. When you're getting the data, how does the data source know what you're sorting by? When you change the page, how do you get a different set of results?

Comment: I'm doing this:
            vm.uploads.sort(function(a,b){
             return new Date(b.uploadDate).getTime()- new Date(a.uploadDate).getTime();
            })

Comment: It already sorts but like I said just those on the particular page. I can sort a column on page 1, and the column I sort will get sorted alphabetically, then when i goto page 2, the same column I sorted is already sorted but just based on the items on that page